# How to open a details activity when an item is clicked in Firebase RecyclerView Cardview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to Implement Onclick Item in recyclerView To open new activity I can pass data from one to another activity but in the code cannot figure out where to Implement on click onclicklistener if anyone is free to help me edit and give intent to Details.class
as I am getting data from firebase its first time to work on firebase any help would be appreciated.

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dekhou.provissionstore.model.Movie;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private FloatingActionButton fab;


    ScaleAnimation shrinkAnim;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private TextView tvNoMovies,tvNoMovies1;
    private Context context;

    //Getting reference to Firebase Database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = database.getReference();

    private static final String userId = "01";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //Initializing our Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        tvNoMovies = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_no_movies);
        //tvNoMovies1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addresstxt);

        //scale animation to shrink floating actionbar
        shrinkAnim = new ScaleAnimation(1.15f, 0f, 1.15f, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            //to enable optimization of recyclerview
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }
        //using staggered grid pattern in recyclerview
        mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        //Say Hello to our new FirebaseUI android Element, i.e., FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Movie,MovieViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Movie, MovieViewHolder>(
                Movie.class,
                R.layout.movie_board_item,
                MovieViewHolder.class,
                //referencing the node where we want the database to store the data from our Object
                mDatabaseReference.child("users").child(userId).child("shops").getRef()
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MovieViewHolder viewHolder, final Movie model, final int position) {
                if(tvNoMovies.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                    tvNoMovies.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                viewHolder.tvMovieName.setText(model.getMovieName());
                viewHolder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
                viewHolder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
                viewHolder.lit.setText(model.getLit());
                viewHolder.lon.setText(model.getLon());
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);


// all your stuff

            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new AddMovieFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
                //animation being used to make floating actionbar disappear
                shrinkAnim.setDuration(400);
                fab.setAnimation(shrinkAnim);
                shrinkAnim.start();
                shrinkAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        //changing floating actionbar visibility to gone on animation end
                        fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {


                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.menu_map) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Intent cinemaIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(cinemaIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            Intent cinemaIntent = new Intent(this, Get_Data.class);
            startActivity(cinemaIntent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            try {
                //try to open page in facebook native app.
                String uri = "fb://page/" + "293069792077";    //Cutsom URL
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(intent);
            }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                //facebook native app isn't available, use browser.
                String uri = "http://touch.facebook.com/pages/x/" + "293069792077";  //Normal URL
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

            Intent cinemaIntent = new Intent(this, About_Us.class);
            startActivity(cinemaIntent);

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    //ViewHolder for our Firebase UI
    public static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvMovieName,address,phone,lit,lon;

        ImageView ivMoviePoster;


        public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvMovieName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address1);
            phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
            lit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.geo);
            lon = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.geo2);


            ivMoviePoster = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_poster);




        }





    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add onClickListener to the itemView for your ViewHolder in populateViewHolder and start the Activity. like the below example.

```
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(MovieViewHolder viewHolder, final Movie model, final int position) {
        if(tvNoMovies.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
            tvNoMovies.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        viewHolder.tvMovieName.setText(model.getMovieName());
        viewHolder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
        viewHolder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
        viewHolder.lit.setText(model.getLit());
        viewHolder.lon.setText(model.getLon());
        Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("model", model);
                intent.putExtra("latitude", model.getLit());
                intent.putExtra("longitude", model.getLon());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
// all your stuff

    }
```

Comment: intent.putExtra("model", model); 
is it to pass all the data to DetailActivity.class all in one?

Comment: Yes, It will send the model object, don't forget to make your Movie object as serializable or parcelable.

Comment: what if I only want to pass Lit=latitude and Lon=longitude to  DetailActivity.class to show loaction of the item Clicked

Comment: I want this image button to open phone app and get phone number to dialer I have this code but app crash when click on imagebutton. 
 
viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(model.getPhone()));

                    }
                });

Comment: Add your crash log.

Comment: String mobileNo = model.getPhone();
                        String uri = "tel:" + mobileNo.trim();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                        startActivity(intent);

just get Application terminated.

Comment: Please add your crash log then only i can check whats going wrong

Comment: cannot get crash log

Answer (score 1):

try this add `onClickListener` in your `populateViewHolder`like this

```
@Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(MovieViewHolder viewHolder, final Movie model, final int position) {
            if(tvNoMovies.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
                tvNoMovies.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            viewHolder.tvMovieName.setText(model.getMovieName());
            viewHolder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
            viewHolder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
            viewHolder.lit.setText(model.getLit());
            viewHolder.lon.setText(model.getLon());
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(model.getMoviePoster()).into(viewHolder.ivMoviePoster);
         viewHolder.tvMovieName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

        }
```